# Do i stash coroutines in one another?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to figure out how coroutines work.

Firstly I need to show 'raw' data without specific values and then make an api call to get missing values and submit it to my RecyclerView. Here's what I tried

```kotlin
userAdapter.submitList(users.data)

users.data.forEachIndexed { index, user ->
    runBlocking {
        val repos = userDetailViewModel.getReposNumber(user.login)
        val followers = userDetailViewModel.getFollowersNumber(user.login)

        val fullUser = user.copy(repos = repos, followers = followers) // repos and followers are Int type
        userAdapter.replaceUser(fullUser, index)
    }
}
```

But this way it doesn't send new values to fullUser so my view doesn't change. How do I wait for those two calls to be completed and only after that send new data to Recycler?

Also there are those two methods. Seems like I don't get them right too

```kotlin
fun getFollowersNumber(login: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    userUseCase.getFollowers(login).size
}
    
fun getReposNumber(login: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    userUseCase.getRepositories(login).size
}
```

I will be grateful for any adwise or links leading to this types of question

EDIT:
Thanks to broot I changed functions to suspend and it seem to work this way now

```kotlin
users.data.forEachIndexed { index, user ->
    lifecycleScope.launch {
    val repos = lifecycleScope.async { 
        userDetailViewModel.getReposNumber(user.login) }.await()
    val followers = lifecycleScope.async { 
        userDetailViewModel.getFollowersNumber(user.login) }.await()

    val fullUser = user.copy(repos = repos, followers = followers)

    userAdapter.replaceUser(fullUser, index)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
suspend fun getFollowersNumber(login: String) = userUseCase.getFollowers(login).size

suspend fun getReposNumber(login: String) = userUseCase.getRepositories(login).size
```

Comment: I wonder how that even compiles. `getFollowersNumber()` and `getReposNumber()` don't return any value, they run the operation in the background. I would assume `user.copy()` line should not compile as you provide `Job` where `Int` is needed. Are you sure this is the exact code you use? You should make these functions suspend and do not launch background coroutines, but return the value directly. I don't even mention `runBlocking` - that code will freeze the UI if executed in the main thread.

Comment: No, you're right, it doesn't compile. I was just trying to show what is exactly hapening in my code for more clarification. Thank you for your comment, I changed methods to suspend functions.

Comment: The only times you should ever touch runBlocking is if you’re working with a third party library that demands to do blocking work in its own background threads or if you are in the process of converting a legacy project that is using background threads and you are partway through the process of converting it to use coroutines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to your code as edited:

`async { }.await()` is pointless code. It is starting a coroutine to do a task, and then waiting for that task in the current coroutine before continuing, so we are effectively doing it synchronously with more steps.

In this case you actually want to be doing those two fetches in parallel, so you could either (1) start both async jobs and *then* await them, or (2) start one async job, do the other task synchronously, and then await the single job.

Also, you should not be going back to the `lifecycleScope` to launch those other coroutines or they will be siblings, not children. If you do bare `async` calls, it will make them child coroutines.

1)

```
users.data.forEachIndexed { index, user ->
  lifecycleScope.launch {
    val repos = async { userDetailViewModel.getReposNumber(user.login) }
    val followers = async { userDetailViewModel.getFollowersNumber(user.login) }

    val fullUser = user.copy(repos = repos.await(), followers = followers.await())

    userAdapter.replaceUser(fullUser, index)
  }
}
```

2. 

```
users.data.forEachIndexed { index, user ->
  lifecycleScope.launch {
    val reposDeferred = async { userDetailViewModel.getReposNumber(user.login) }
    val followers = userDetailViewModel.getFollowersNumber(user.login)

    val fullUser = user.copy(repos = reposDeferred.await(), followers = followers)

    userAdapter.replaceUser(fullUser, index)
  }
}
```

However, you should consider doing fetching type work like this in the ViewModel and updating the data there so it is preserved through context changes. Doing it in the activity like this means it will have to refetch the data every time the screen rotates.